# Micronaut return HttpResponse.serverError in controller not captured in unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, micronaut

I am testing a micronaut controller. The controller code as below:

```
  @Get("/")
    HttpResponse<String> getData(String crsNumber ) {
        try {
            final HttpResponse response = formDataService.getData(crsNumber);
            return response;

        } catch (HttpClientException e) {
            return HttpResponse.serverError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The unit test code as below:

```
when(formDataService.getData(anyString())).thenThrow(new HttpClientException("FormService Internal Error!"));

final HttpResponse rs = formControllerClient.getData("test");
Assertions.assertEquals(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, rs.getStatus());
```

When throw the HttpClientException, the Controller did capture it, and run to the return sentence:

```
return HttpResponse.serverError(e.getMessage());
```

but in the unit test, the

```
Assertions.assertEquals(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, rs.getStatus());
```

never reached, cause it throws

```
Internal Server Error
io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Internal Server Error
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$11.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:2046)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$11.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:1964)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:190)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsClientHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsClientHandler.java:185)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Can you show the source code for the type that `formControllerClient` points to?

Comment: And can you show your mock chain in your unit test and the full code of your controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue here: Micronaut will throw a HttpClientResponseException if you return a error code over 400.

Full code of unit test as now:

```
@Test
public void callServiceErrorTest() throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, JOSEException {
    when(formDataService.getData(anyString())).thenThrow(new HttpClientException("FormService Internal Error!"));

    final HttpClientResponseException exception = Assertions.assertThrows(HttpClientResponseException.class, () -> {
        formControllerClient.getData(jwtString);
    });

    Assertions.assertEquals(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, exception.getStatus());
}
```